# Updating object values in class

Tags: python, class, object, return

I have a question about how to return the update value of an object in a class and then use that in another function in the same class. Here is my old code.

```
class Vector:
def __init__(self, a):
    self.a = a
    assert type(self.a) == list
    for i in self.a:
        assert type(i) == int or type(i) == float
def dim(self):
    return len(self.a)
def __getitem__(self, i):
    assert i >= 1 and i <= self.dim()
    return self.a[i-1]
def __setitem__(self, i, x):
    assert i >= 1 and i <= self.dim()
    self.a[i-1] = x
    return self.a[i-1]
def __str__(self):
    return 'Vector: ' + str(self.a)
def __add__(self, other):
    assert type(other.a) == list and other.dim() == self.dim()
    n = []
    for j in range(self.dim()):
        n.append(self.a[j]+other.a[j])
    self.a = n 
    return self.a
```

so when i'm running this test case:

```
v1 = Vector([2, 3, 4])
v2 = Vector([1, 2, 3])
str(v1 + v2)
```

my output is `'[3, 5, 7]'` which means it is only following `return self.a` and not the `__str__` function however i want my output to be `'Vector: [3, 5, 7]'` as it should be following the `__str__` function. I fixed this by returning `Vector(self.a)` in the `__add__` function but i dont know why this works. Can anyone explain why that works, and why `return self.a` does not simply update the object value and run the `__str__` function instead?

Note: Python uses following equivalent notations:

```
v[i]       ==  v.__getitem__(i)
v[i] = x   ==  v.__setitem__(i, x)
str(v)     ==  v.__str__()
v + other  ==  v.__add__(other)
```

Comment: Yeah, because your `__add__` returns `self.a` which is *a list*. `self` is a `Vector`, `self.a` is a list. Return something like `Vector(self.a)`. But honestly, do you really want `+` to work inplace? That not typical in Python, which is what you've done... However, since you have done that, you could just return `self`.

Comment: Also `__setitem__` probably shouldn't return *anything*.

Comment: Thanks juanpa.arrivillaga! I see now the problem of returning a list. But I still  don't quite understand what you mean by having `+` to work in place. Also yeah you are right about `__setitem__`, i removed the return.

Comment: I mean that `__add__` modifies one of your objects, when it should return a *new* object. Consider the way lists work already with the `+` operator: `a = [1,2]; b = [3, 5]` Then try `print(a + b)` and you will see `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, but `a` and `b` will not change! In your implementation, `a` would change!

Comment: So just remove the line `self.a = n` and just `return Vector(n)`

Comment: ah yes, that makes sense, because Vector(n) would update self.a anyways through the initialization function

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't update `self.a` for the vectors you are adding together, but of a *new* vector.